# Return document collection as json from firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I return a collection of documents from firestore database.
For example, I have a collection named countries in cloud firestore, and I want to fetch all the country names and ids as json , like this

```
[
    {
        "countryId" : 1,
        "countryName" : "Any"
    },
    {
        "countryId" : 2,
        "countryName" : "India"
    }
]
```

Now I am doing a foreach on the snapshot. Is that the only way to convert a collection to json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is correct.  You have to iterate each document in the collection/query, and generate the JSON yourself from there.  There is no single operation for converting a collection to some other format in its entirety.

Comment: This is the only answer which shouldn't be accepted. All the others reveal the .data() method on the snapshot which gives what the OP wants, and there's no need to manually convert it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to get the collection without loop.

```
const companies = async (req, res) =>{
    const {id} = req.query;
    db.collection("users")
        .where("role", "==", "vendor")
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            var docs = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
            res.status(200).json(docs);
        });
}
```

Comment: method "then" doesnt exist :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
const db = admin.firestore();   
......
......
async function getCollection (req, res){ 
try{

  let result = await db.collection('collection_name').get(); //TODO: add query if needed
  let response = [];

  result.forEach(doc => {
    response.push(doc.data());
  });

  return res.send( { "collection" : response} );

 }catch(err){
  res.status(500).send(err);
 }

}
```